# Angular 2 / 4 Server Side Processing for Datatables not displaying data

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Angular 4.2.4
Angular-Datatables 4.2.0

**Html**

```html
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"></table>
```

**Component**

```js
ngOnInit() {

    this.dtOptions = {
        ajax: {
            url: "http://localhost:8880/nmets/api/manifest/search",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            error: function(xhr, error, code) { console.log(error); },
            success: function(result) {console.log(JSON.stringify(result))},
            data: function(data) {
                data['dto'] = this.manifest;
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            }.bind(this)
        },
        columns: [

            { data: "departureTime", title: 'Departure Time', }

        ],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        pageLength: 25,
    };
}
```

When the page loads I see the table header ("Departure Time") and I see the word "Processing...". 
I see the Post request and the server responds as follows (shortened):

**Server Response**

```js
{"draw":1,
"recordsTotal":109,
"recordsFiltered":109,
"data":[ 
{"departureTime":"2:18 pm"},
{"departureTime":"2:55 pm"},
{"departureTime":"8:54 pm"},
{"departureTime":"9:10 pm"},
{"departureTime":"12:28 am"},
{"departureTime":"12:33 am"},
...
]}
```

I can see the results from the 'success' callback, but the table does not get populated, and the 'Processing...' also continues to display.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing this `data['dto'] = this.manifest;` to this: `{ ...data, dto: this.manifest }`.And don't stringify the return, just do `return data`.

Comment: That code is inside a function, not inside an object. If I do that I will get a compilation error. Besides, the data is going to the server as expected, if I don't stringify it,it will not send the request body in json format, which is what the format expected by the server. My understanding is that the 'data' property is used for the request, not to handle the server response.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad. That callback indeed is intercepting the request object being sent to the server... Have you tried posting this issue in the DataTables forum? As an alternative,I could purpose to use this library that does the same but is fully supported and integrated with Angular: https://www.ag-grid.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `success` handler, remove that. You dont need `type` or `contentType` either :

```js
ajax: {
  url: "http://localhost:8880/nmets/api/manifest/search",
  error: function(xhr, error, code) { console.log(error); },
  data: function(data) {
    data['dto'] = this.manifest;
    return JSON.stringify(data);
  }.bind(this)
},
```

The `success` handler must never be overwritten since it is used internally by DataTables. If you need a success handler use the `dataSrc` callback instead. See **https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#Types**

`contentType` is redundant since DatTables will try to parse the response anyway. You could set `type`, it is not an error, but if there is no particular need for a `POST` request it is just garbage.

Comment: Thanks, It worked.  I didn't realize I was overriding the success callback. I was just using it for debugging purposes.